# How to handle the situation of assert caused while accessing non existent document in flutter firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to gracefully handle a situation where provided document path is totally invalid. E.g. /fakeCollection/fakedocID. Here collection /fakeCollection is also non existent.

I have tried putting `FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(_docID)` inside try-catch. And also tried checking for `onError()`. But, None of these workarounds helped.

Firebase is throwing assert() for invalid collection.

As a final resort, I have added additional checks to ensure that collection part of the document ID path is correct. With that, I was able to detect if a document is non existent or not.

If you are aware of a better solution, please suggest.

Edit:
This is the code that I was trying to execute.

```
Widget getBody() {
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .doc('/nonExistentCollection/fakeDocID')
          .get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text ('Invalid document case');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          var data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          var rrDMDoc = ResourceReservationDirectMessage.fromJson(
              'ignore', 'ignore', data);

          return Text ('All Good');
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  );
}
```

In the above code, I have developed a utility function `getBody()` that will return a Text widget depending on the validity or nonvalidity of the provided doc path.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact error message you get, its stack trace, and the minimum code that any of us can copy/paste/run to reproduce the error. Together those are known as a minimal reproduction, so I also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My apologies for not sharing the code and debug log. Today when I tried reproducing the same issue, I am not seeing the assert() issue. Something must have changed in my code since yesterday.

Comment: That's good to hear Navin  --- It's actually surprisingly common to hear that problems disappear when creating a minimal repro, so that might be something to keep in mind for next time too.